# Remove div message using CSS animate and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I print success message using PHP like this :

```
<div class='alert alert-success'>Success!!</div>
```

I have this CSS3 Animate:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.animated.hinge {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
          animation-duration: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
}

.fadeOutUp {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeOutUp;
          animation-name: fadeOutUp;
}
```

Now, I need to remove success message with my CSS Animate (fadeOutUp) after 5 seconds using jQuery. How do can i create this?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a hide a class which hide your element setting the opacity to 0 with a transition and add this class to your div with JavaScript.

CSS

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1000ms;
}
```

JS

```
function fadeOut(el){
  el.classList.add('hide');
}

div = document.getElementById('yourDiv');
setTimeout(function(){
  fadeOut(div);
}, 5000);
```

HTML

```
<div id='yourDiv' class='alert alert-success'>Success!!</div>
```

Checkout this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/ZYBbqe).

Comment: @T-M Pay attention is not jQuery fadeOut, is pure CSS and JS you just need to add the class 'hide' to your element using JS.

Comment: @T-M If you want to use your css class the pattern is still the same just replace my class .hide for your class .fadeOutUp

Comment: I think something is wrong with your animation. I don't know exactly what kind of effect need but check this codepen:(http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/ZYBbqe), is working ok.

Comment: my problem in your demo so message remove and show again. i need to remove with any css animation. Like :http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Are you talking of the codepen demo? I cant see what you are saying. In the codepen de message was removed ok and is not shown anymore.

Comment: Sure. I check with chrome worked true(you right) but in FF not work !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68019/discussion-between-ianaya89-and-t-m).

Comment: I forgot to update the @moz animation. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
setTimeout(animateUp, 5000);

function animateUp() {
    $(".alert").css({'-webkit-animation' : 'fadeOutUp 5s infinite'});
}
```

or update your `.fadeOutUp` CSS to

```
.fadeOutUp {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOutUp 5s infinite;
     animation: fadeOutUp 5s infinite;
}
```

Then you can do

```
setTimeout(animateUp, 5000);

function animateUp() {
    $(".alert").addClass("fadeOutUp");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uba9Lwj/)